# What is missing in my if statement to validate Credit Card function and how to return a value in the text?

Tags: javascript, function, document-body

Missing link to credit card validation using only JavaScript. Needs to have atleast two different digits and all digits should not be the same. I am unable to return values in the text please help thank you. Here is a link to the [exercise](https://www.teaching-materials.org/javascript/exercises/creditcard).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Credit Card Validation</title>
<meta name="description" content="CHANGE THIS CONTENT DESCRIPTION">

</head>

<body>
  <span>Credit Card Number* :</span>

  <input class="inputForm" type="number" id="ccn" name="inputStealMoney" 
placeholder="Enter Credit Card Number"><span class="restriction" id="CCNSpan"></span>
  <button type="button" onclick="CCNSpan">Submit</button>
  <br>
  <p id="CCNSpan">Text</p>
  <script>

    function funcCall() {
      validFormCCN();
    }
    function validFormCCN() {
      var x, textC;
      x = document.getElementById('ccn').value;
      //If statement below is blank in the last () paranthesis. It needs to be filled with 'different numbers' to work
      if (isNaN(x) && (x%2) ==0 && x.length==16 && ()) {
    /*The if statement above is NaN() and x%2==0 is even and x.length is 16 digits and the blank () paranthesis where all the digits cannot be the same with atleast two different digits*/ 
        return true;
     }
       else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("CCNSpan").innerHTML = textC;

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well I think I didn't explain my problem clearly. I am a beginner so my instructor was giving us simple ways to make a function work. These answers show me that there multiple ways to go about it but these are implementations I can't use in front of my instructor yet. Not until I can understand and practice with them. I used this from my classmate (x%2222222222222222) and changed the && to || for ensuring there are atleast two different numbers. Im grateful to wp78de and Tim Biegeleisen for responding. I hope to get to your level and pay it forward.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the following regex pattern:

```
(\d)(?!\1{15})\d{15}
```

This asserts that the credit number contains 16 digits, and that the first number does *not* repeat for the next 15 digits.  This implies that there are at least 2 numbers which are not the same.

```js
var str = "1111111111111111";
var patt = new RegExp("(\\d)(?!\\1{15})\\d{15}");
var res = patt.test(str);
console.log(res);
str = "1111111115111111";
res = patt.test(str);
console.log(res);
```

Of course, in practice, in a production e-commerce site, you would be using much more complex regular expressions.  Visa, MasterCard, etc. have rules for how their credit card numbers are formed.  You may visit [this link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks somewhat like an attempt to implement the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm). Implementations for many languages including [JavaScript](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Luhn_test_of_credit_card_numbers#JavaScript) can be easily found.

```
var luhn10 = function(a,b,c,d,e) {
  for(d = +a[b = a.length-1], e=0; b--;)
    c = +a[b], d += ++e % 2 ? 2 * c % 10 + (c > 4) : c;
  return !(d%10)
};
```

However, not all credit card companies use the Luhn algorithm. This it is recommended to use a library function to validate credit card numbers, e.g. the [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/creditcard-method/). Another common implementation is provided by [Braemoor](https://www.braemoor.co.uk/software/creditcard.shtml) and a regex-based JS version can be found [here](http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256CC70060A01B).

```js
  function validateCcn(value) {
  // Accept only spaces, digits and dashes
 if ( /[^0-9 \-]+/.test( value ) ) {
  return false;
 }
 var nCheck = 0,
  nDigit = 0,
  bEven = false,
  n, cDigit;
 value = value.replace( /\D/g, "" );
 if ( value.length < 13 || value.length > 19 ) {
  return false;
 }
 for ( n = value.length - 1; n >= 0; n-- ) {
  cDigit = value.charAt( n );
  nDigit = parseInt( cDigit, 10 );
  if ( bEven ) {
   if ( ( nDigit *= 2 ) > 9 ) {
    nDigit -= 9;
   }
  }
  nCheck += nDigit;
  bEven = !bEven;
 }
 return ( nCheck % 10 ) === 0;
  }
  console.log(validateCcn('1234-1234-1234-1234'));
  console.log(validateCcn('378282246310005'));
```